# startBluetoothSco keeps jumping between SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTING and SCO_AUDIO_STATE_DISCONNECTED

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

So I'm building this app to support bluetooth headset. So here is my code:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private int activitiesCount;
    private BluetoothControllerImpl bluetoothController;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bluetoothController = new BluetoothControllerImpl(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        onActivityPaused();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        onActivityResume();
    }

    protected void onActivityResume() {
        if (activitiesCount++ == 0) { // on become foreground
            bluetoothController.start();
        }
    }

    protected void onActivityPaused() {
        if (--activitiesCount == 0) { // on become background
            bluetoothController.stop();
        }
    }

    private boolean isInForeground() {
        return activitiesCount > 0;
    }

    private class BluetoothControllerImpl extends BluetoothController {

        public BluetoothControllerImpl(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        public void onHeadsetDisconnected() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Bluetooth headset disconnected");
        }

        @Override
        public void onHeadsetConnected() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Bluetooth headset connected");

            if (isInForeground() && !bluetoothController.isOnHeadsetSco()) {
                bluetoothController.start();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScoAudioDisconnected() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Bluetooth sco audio finished");
            bluetoothController.stop();

            if (isInForeground()) {
                bluetoothController.start();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScoAudioConnected() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Bluetooth sco audio started");
        }
    }
}
```

BluetoothController.java

```
public abstract class BluetoothController {

    private Context mContext;

    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;

    private AudioManager mAudioManager;

    private boolean mIsCountDownOn;
    private boolean mIsStarting;
    private boolean mIsOnHeadsetSco;
    private boolean mIsStarted;

    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothController";

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param context
     */
    public BluetoothController(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        mAudioManager = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    }

    /**
     * Call this to start BluetoothController functionalities.
     *
     * @return The return value of startBluetooth()
     */
    public boolean start() {
        if (!mIsStarted) {
            mIsStarted = true;

            mIsStarted = startBluetooth();
        }

        return mIsStarted;
    }

    /**
     * Should call this on onResume or onDestroy.
     * Unregister broadcast receivers and stop Sco audio connection
     * and cancel count down.
     */
    public void stop() {
        if (mIsStarted) {
            mIsStarted = false;

            stopBluetooth();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return true if audio is connected through headset.
     */
    public boolean isOnHeadsetSco() {
        return mIsOnHeadsetSco;
    }

    public abstract void onHeadsetDisconnected();

    public abstract void onHeadsetConnected();

    public abstract void onScoAudioDisconnected();

    public abstract void onScoAudioConnected();

    /**
     * Register for bluetooth headset connection states and Sco audio states.
     * Try to connect to bluetooth headset audio by calling startBluetoothSco().
     * This is a work around for API < 11 to detect if a headset is connected before
     * the application starts.
     * <p/>
     * The official documentation for startBluetoothSco() states
     * <p/>
     * "This method can be used by applications wanting to send and received audio to/from
     * a bluetooth SCO headset while the phone is not in call."
     * <p/>
     * Does this mean that startBluetoothSco() would fail if the connected bluetooth device
     * is not a headset?
     * <p/>
     * Thus if a call to startBluetoothSco() is successful, i.e mBroadcastReceiver will receive
     * an ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED with intent extra SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTED, then
     * we assume that a headset is connected.
     *
     * @return false if device does not support bluetooth or current platform does not supports
     * use of SCO for off call.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private boolean startBluetooth() {
        Log.d(TAG, "startBluetooth");

        // Device support bluetooth
        if (mBluetoothAdapter != null) {
            if (mAudioManager.isBluetoothScoAvailableOffCall()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "isBluetoothScoAvailableOffCall");
                mContext.registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver,
                        new IntentFilter(android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED));
                mContext.registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver,
                        new IntentFilter(android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED));
                mContext.registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver,
                        new IntentFilter(AudioManager.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED));

                mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onAudioFocusChange focusChange=" + focusChange);
                        }
                    }, AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);

                // Need to set audio mode to MODE_IN_CALL for call to startBluetoothSco() to succeed.
                mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);

                mIsCountDownOn = true;
                // mCountDown repeatedly tries to start bluetooth Sco audio connection.
                mCountDown.start();

                // need for audio sco, see mBroadcastReceiver
                mIsStarting = true;

                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Unregister broadcast receivers and stop Sco audio connection
     * and cancel count down.
     */
    private void stopBluetooth() {
        Log.d(TAG, "stopBluetooth");

        if (mIsCountDownOn) {
            mIsCountDownOn = false;
            mCountDown.cancel();
        }

        // Need to stop Sco audio connection here when the app
        // change orientation or close with headset still turns on.
        mContext.unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
        mAudioManager.stopBluetoothSco();
        mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
    }

    /**
     * Handle headset and Sco audio connection states.
     */
    private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @SuppressWarnings({"deprecation", "synthetic-access"})
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (action.equals(android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED 1");
                android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice mConnectedHeadset = intent.getParcelableExtra(android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                BluetoothClass bluetoothClass = mConnectedHeadset.getBluetoothClass();
                if (bluetoothClass != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED 2");
                    // Check if device is a headset. Besides the 2 below, are there other
                    // device classes also qualified as headset?
                    int deviceClass = bluetoothClass.getDeviceClass();
                    if (deviceClass == BluetoothClass.Device.AUDIO_VIDEO_HANDSFREE
                            || deviceClass == BluetoothClass.Device.AUDIO_VIDEO_WEARABLE_HEADSET) {

                        Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED deviceClass=" + deviceClass);
                        // start bluetooth Sco audio connection.
                        // Calling startBluetoothSco() always returns faIL here,
                        // that why a count down timer is implemented to call
                        // startBluetoothSco() in the onTick.
                        mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
                        mIsCountDownOn = true;
                        mCountDown.start();

                        // override this if you want to do other thing when the device is connected.
                        onHeadsetConnected();
                    }
                }

                Log.d(TAG, mConnectedHeadset.getName() + " connected");
            } else if (action.equals(android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Headset disconnected");

                if (mIsCountDownOn) {
                    mIsCountDownOn = false;
                    mCountDown.cancel();
                }

                mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);

                // override this if you want to do other thing when the device is disconnected.
                onHeadsetDisconnected();
            } else if (action.equals(AudioManager.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED)) {
                int state = intent.getIntExtra(AudioManager.EXTRA_SCO_AUDIO_STATE,
                        AudioManager.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_ERROR);

                Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED state=" + state);

                if (state == AudioManager.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTED) {
                    mIsOnHeadsetSco = true;

                    if (mIsStarting) {
                        // When the device is connected before the application starts,
                        // ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED will not be received, so call onHeadsetConnected here
                        mIsStarting = false;
                        onHeadsetConnected();
                    }

                    if (mIsCountDownOn) {
                        mIsCountDownOn = false;
                        mCountDown.cancel();
                    }

                    // override this if you want to do other thing when Sco audio is connected.
                    onScoAudioConnected();

                    Log.d(TAG, "Sco connected");
                } else if (state == AudioManager.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Sco disconnected");

                    // Always receive SCO_AUDIO_STATE_DISCONNECTED on call to startBluetooth()
                    // which at that stage we do not want to do anything. Thus the if condition.
                    if (!mIsStarting) {
                        mIsOnHeadsetSco = false;

                        // Need to call stopBluetoothSco(), otherwise startBluetoothSco()
                        // will not be successful.
                        mAudioManager.stopBluetoothSco();
                        mAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(false);
                        mAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);

                        // override this if you want to do other thing when Sco audio is disconnected.
                        onScoAudioDisconnected();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    /**
     * Try to connect to audio headset in onTick.
     */
    private CountDownTimer mCountDown = new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {

        @SuppressWarnings("synthetic-access")
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // When this call is successful, this count down timer will be canceled.
            try {
                mAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
                mAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
                mAudioManager.startBluetoothSco();
            } catch (Exception ignored) {

            }
            Log.d(TAG, "\nonTick start bluetooth Sco");
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("synthetic-access")
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // Calls to startBluetoothSco() in onStick are not successful.
            // Should implement something to inform user of this failure
            mIsCountDownOn = false;
            mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);

            Log.d(TAG, "\nonFinish fail to connect to headset audio");
        }
    };
}
```

So I made sure that the bluetooth headset (Bose wireless headphones) is connected to my tablet (Acer running Lollipop) by playing youtube videos and recording sounds. When I try to run the above code I get the following output:

```
BluetoothController: startBluetooth
BluetoothController: isBluetoothScoAvailableOffCall
BluetoothController: ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED state=0
BluetoothController: Sco disconnected
BluetoothController: onTick start bluetooth Sco
BluetoothController: ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED state=2
BluetoothController: onTick start bluetooth Sco
BluetoothController: onTick start bluetooth Sco
BluetoothController: onTick start bluetooth Sco
BluetoothController: ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED state=0
BluetoothController: Sco disconnected
BluetoothController: ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED state=2
BluetoothController: onTick start bluetooth Sco
BluetoothController: onTick start bluetooth Sco
BluetoothController: onTick start bluetooth Sco
BluetoothController: ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED state=0
BluetoothController: Sco disconnected
BluetoothController: ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED state=2
BluetoothController: onTick start bluetooth Sco
BluetoothController: onTick start bluetooth Sco
BluetoothController: onTick start bluetooth Sco
BluetoothController: ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED state=0
BluetoothController: Sco disconnected
BluetoothController: ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED state=2
BluetoothController: onTick start bluetooth Sco
BluetoothController: onTick start bluetooth Sco
BluetoothController: onTick start bluetooth Sco
BluetoothController: ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED state=0
BluetoothController: Sco disconnected
BluetoothController: ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED state=2
BluetoothController: onTick start bluetooth Sco
BluetoothController: onTick start bluetooth Sco
BluetoothController: onTick start bluetooth Sco
BluetoothController: ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED state=0
BluetoothController: Sco disconnected
BluetoothController: onTick start bluetooth Sco
BluetoothController: ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED state=2
BluetoothController: onTick start bluetooth Sco
BluetoothController: onTick start bluetooth Sco
BluetoothController: ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED state=0
BluetoothController: Sco disconnected
BluetoothController: onFinish fail to connect to headset audio
```

I never get the start bluetooth Sco method to succeed. It's always jumping between connecting and disconnected. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you solve the problem? I have same issue and the answer doen't work. I shoulde understand wich is the real reason why the state goes 0 (disconnected) and not 1(connected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the tablet that I was using doesn't support phone audio in the bluetooth settings.

So in order to make sure that the bluetooth connection works you need to go to settings->bluetooth and click on the settings icon next to your paired bluetooth headset. You should make sure that there is "Phone Audio" and "Media Audio" checked. If you're missing "Phone Audio" you will have the same output of connecting disconnecting as mine.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I had same kind of problem even when device supported Bluetooth phone audio and settings were correct.

When I called startBluetoothSco() immediately after receiving BluetoothHeadset.STATE_CONNECTED event, SCO state went from SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTING to SCO_AUDIO_STATE_DISCONNECTED.  I got the issue fixed by introducing 1 sec delay to calling of startBluetoothSco() after BluetoothHeadset.STATE_CONNECTED event:

```
BluetoothHeadset.STATE_CONNECTED -> {
    if (isAudioFocused()) {
        Timer("Sco", false).schedule(1000) {
            myAudioManager.startBluetoothSco()
        }
}
```